# React setState not become false again

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a pretty simple code, which I use setState.
The default value is false, and there is a function called openQueryDetails in which I change the value of setState to true (means displaying commonents).

The another function (closeQueryDetails), return the setState to false and needs to hide the displayed components.

Make setState true does work, but to return false and hide the component does not work.

When I run with a debugger I see that **it does come and go into the closeQueryDetails** function, but in the end, the view does not change and stays the same, as when the setState was true.

```
function Feed(props) {
  const [queryDetailsIsOpen, setQueryDetailsIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function openQueryDetails()  { setQueryDetailsIsOpen(true);  }
  function closeQueryDetails() { setQueryDetailsIsOpen(false); }
  
return (
    <div onClick={openQueryDetails}>
      ...
      {queryDetailsIsOpen && <QueryResultView query={props.query} onClose={closeQueryDetails} />}
      {queryDetailsIsOpen && <Backdrop onClose={closeQueryDetails}/>}
    </div>
  );
}

function Backdrop(props) {
    return <div className="backdrop" onClick={props.onClose} />;
}
```

Thanks for the help!  (-:

Comment: What is the view when queryDetailsIsOpen is false? Can you add that?

Comment: I think click on the QueryResultView and Backdrop component may be propagating the click event all the way up to the parent. You could pass the event object to openQueryDetails and closeQueryDetails and then use event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Backdrop` component is in the `div` that has attribute `onClick={openQueryDetails}`. So your calling close then immediately open again. Please look `event.stopPropagation()`. If you add this call to your close function, this will prevent further propagations.